# GraphQL and Python with JSon - Syntax Error with Unescaped characters

Tags: python, json, graphql

I am trying to POST a GraphQL Mutation and am getting a syntax error that I can't figure out.  I saw that there was a bug regarding escaped/unescaped characters.  I have tried escaping, double quotes, single quotes, no quotes.  I can't seem to get past this issue.  Traceback under the code.

```
# http headers for api call
headers = {
    'accept': "application/json",
    'content-type':"application/json",
    'authorization': "bearer " + token,
}

# create inventory variable for mutation 
# will convert the csv to the json input in production
inventory:[{"supplier_id":24522,"supplier_part_number":"1-1002-9-SN","quantity_on_hand":5,"item_next_availability_date":"05-01-2018T00:00:00", "discontinued":true}]


# payload of the json query to pass to the API
#GraphQL Query to pull in Purchase Order Data 
payload = '''
{"query":"mutation save_inventory($inventory: [inventoryInput]!) {
  inventory {
    save(inventory: $inventory, dry_run: true) {
      handle
    }
  }
}"}
'''

# send API call and assign response to variable
response = requests.post(api_url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Error I can't figure out below.

```
  {"errors":[{"message":"Syntax Error GraphQL (1:1) Unexpected <EOF>\n\n1: \n   ^\n","category":"graphql","locations":[{"l
    ine":1,"column":1}]}]}
```

Comment: Could it be the line break after `payload = '''`? What happens if you change it to `payload = '''{"query":"mutat...`?

Comment: That got me past that error and on to the next, thanks! @jDo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Python's rusty, but I believe you want to use `json` instead of `data`. You're also not passing in the `inventory` variable you defined. Try something like:

```
json = {
  "query": '''   
    mutation save_inventory($inventory: [inventoryInput]!) {
      inventory {
        save(inventory: $inventory, dry_run: true) {
        handle
      }
    }
  }
  ''',
  "variables": {
    "inventory": inventory
  }
}

response = requests.post(api_url, json=json, headers=headers)
```